# readOuterXml(), Input is not proper UTF-8, indicate encoding

Tags: php, xml, utf-8, character-encoding, xmlreader

I'm using **[XMLReader](https://www.php.net/xmlreader)** to parse a large XML file from a third party, file size is 1GB+. The XML file specifies the encoding as UTF8 (`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>`), although it isn't.

XMLReader throws an error because of the unknown encoding type, but not until it's already processed most of the file.

**Exception message:**

> Input is not proper UTF-8, indicate encoding

I have determined that the *real* encoding of the file is `ISO-8859-1`, and it will work fine if I manually specify this when calling `$reader->open()`.

The problem is that my script needs to parse unknown files from the database, so it needs to rely on the encoding type specified within the file. I need to find a way to parse any file regardless of its encoding, are there any suggestions for doing this?

Comment: You would have to confirm what encoding the file is in before you parse it. Since you can hardly do this by reading the file into memory, I'd say you either do it by reading it line by line and checking each line, or by using a command line tool like `iconv` which can will do the checking without reading it into memory all at once.

Comment: @deceze: Thanks for the suggestion, I found [Enca](http://cihar.com/software/enca/) and will use this to detect the encoding. The server is Windows so I will have to compile myself before I can test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that [vim](http://www.vim.org/) is pretty good at converting from one encoding to another.

My trick is to parse the file normally, and when the encoding error is encountered just re-encode the file with vim and start parsing again.

Here's the rough idea:

```
$xmlFile = '/path/to/file.xml';

// Parse the file in a loop
while(...)
{

    try
    {
        // Normal parsing logic...

        $reader->readOuterXml();

        //...
    }
    catch(Exception $ex)
    {
        $encoding = getXMLEncoding($xmlFile) ?: 'utf-8';

        exec(sprintf(VIM_PATH . ' -c "set fileencoding=%s" -c "wq" "%s"', $encoding, $xmlFile));

        // File has been re-encoded
        // The real encoding should now match the declared encoding

        // -> Go back to the beginning and parse the file again
    }

}
```

Using this method might garble 1 or 2 chars, but it's way better than completely failed parsing. Ideally the 3rd party would mark their files correctly.

My system is Windows, so the vim arguments might be different on Linux (*don't know*).

Answer (score -2):

Use [simplexml_load_file](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.simplexml-load-file.php) to parse XML. In order to avoid encoding problems, use [utf8_encode](https://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.utf8-encode.php) on data.

Comment: 1) A 1GB XML file will hardly be parseable by loading it into memory all at once. 2) Basically the same problem with running the entire file through `utf8_encode`. 3) The OP doesn't know what encoding the file is in, so `utf8_encode` is hardly a blanket solution here.